# C# LINQ Expression getting rather long

Tags: c#, linq

So, I have a list of objects (containers) in my code and I want to check if the container I will add, will contribute to the maximum weight on top of each container (`container.MaxWeightOnTop`). I have created this function:

```
    private bool TooMuchWeight(Container referenceContainer)
    {
        var tempList = _containers;
        tempList.Add(referenceContainer);
        SortStack(tempList);

        foreach (var container in tempList)
        {
            var index = tempList.FindIndex(c => c == container);
            var weightOnContainer = tempList.Where(c => tempList.FindIndex(i => i == container) > index)
                .Sum(c => container.Weight);

            if (weightOnContainer > Container.MaxWeightOnTop)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see it gets rather long, my IDE even suggest this LINQ expression for the entire foreach loop:

```
 return (from container in tempList
            let index = tempList.FindIndex(c => c == container)
            select tempList.Where(c => tempList.FindIndex(i => i == container) > index)
                .Sum(c => container.Weight)).All(weightOnContainer => weightOnContainer <= Container.MaxWeightOnTop);
```

Even when I use the .GetRange function it still remains long:

```
return tempList
            .Select(container =>
                tempList.GetRange(tempList.FindIndex(c => c == container), Length).Sum(c => c.Weight))
            .All(weightOnContainer => weightOnContainer <= Container.MaxWeightOnTop);
```

**Question**: Is it possible to compress this expression?

Comment: Long code is not a bad code, The code is a way of communication so other can understand what the code does, for the machine itself it does matter at all how many line of code there are. personally I can understand the first revision of your code a lot better, it is descriptive and good.

Comment: to be frank there is not enough code here to tell if it can be cleaned up. The entire class will probably be needed for that, BUT, as shahar said, less code does not mean better also linq does also not mean better. i think this should probable be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of readability and maybe even a little bit performance, I think your code could leverage indexed [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) overload and value tuples:

```
    var tempList = _containers;
    tempList.Add(referenceContainer);
    SortStack(tempList);
    var indexed = tempList.Select((container, index) => (container, index)).ToList();
    foreach (var (container, index) in indexed)
    {
        var weightOnContainer = indexed
            .Where((c, i) => i > index)
            .Sum((c, i) => c.Weight);

        if (weightOnContainer > Container.MaxWeightOnTop)
            return false;
    }
```

Also in original version `.Sum(c => container.Weight)` clause looks a little bit funky to me, should not it be `.Sum(c => c.Weight)`?

Comment: what version of c# are you using? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @jellehuibregtse sorry, missed at least one usage of `tempList` which needed to be substituted to `tempList`

Comment: I didn't see that mb. Thanks for answering anyways!

Comment: @jellehuibregtse glad if it helped!